# Richfaces a4j:queue oncomplete doesn't work with Richfaces 4.2.x or 4.3.x

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

We're upgrading from Richfaces 3.3 to Richfaces 4.2.  We were using the `oncomplete` attribute on the `a4j:queue` component to remap our JavaScript controllers after Ajax requests. After upgrading, the `oncomplete` attribute no longer works.  It appears to not be supported in Richfaces 4.x.

The code looks something like this:

```
<a4j:queue requestDelay="500" oncomplete="alert('1')" />
<h:form>
<h:commandLink value="Common link">
<a4j:ajax />
</h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

There are a number of open issues in the Richfaces issue tracker related to this issue:

- https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-9324
- https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-13023
- https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-11711

My question is, **is there a way to workaround the removal of the `oncomplete` attribute from the `a4j:queue` component**? We'd like to re-bind our JavaScript controllers after all of the Ajax requests have completed.  It seems like we're not the only folks to encounter this issue.  I'm curious about how others have worked around the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what we finally settled on.

We already had an `a4j:status` element that we were using to display the little spinner that displays while AJAX requests are being handled.  We remap our controllers in the onstop element on the `a4j:status` element.

```
    <a4j:status onstop="alert('1');">
        <f:facet name="start">
            <div id="throbber" class="throbber-visible">Loading...</div>
        </f:facet>
    </a4j:status>
```